# SELECT query on unique number field returns no rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

This is a cross-post of an issue I field on the GORM Github repo. I am unsure if the issue is with Postgres 11 or with GORM.

See: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/2872

I have a table containing an ID as primary key and only one more column (mega_herz) which is a numeric(7,3). The numeric field also has a unique constraint on it. When I do the following query from pgadmin4 or psql I get one row as a response:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "ttnmapper_frequencies" 
WHERE ("ttnmapper_frequencies"."mega_herz" = 868.3) 
ORDER BY "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id" ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

But when I do the same query via GORM it does not return any results, and when I try and do an insert it fails:

```
(/home/jpmeijers/go/src/ttnmapper-postgres-insert-raw/main.go:342) 
[2020-02-03 14:52:28]  [3.07ms]  
SELECT * 
FROM "ttnmapper_frequencies"  
WHERE ("ttnmapper_frequencies"."mega_herz" = 868.3)
ORDER BY "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id" ASC 
LIMIT 1  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/jpmeijers/go/src/ttnmapper-postgres-insert-raw/main.go:342) 
[2020-02-03 14:52:28]  [2.10ms]  
INSERT  INTO "ttnmapper_frequencies" 
("mega_herz") 
VALUES 
(868.3) 
RETURNING "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id"  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 

(/home/jpmeijers/go/src/ttnmapper-postgres-insert-raw/main.go:345) 
[2020-02-03 14:52:28]  pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ttnmapper_frequencies_mega_herz_key"
```

Why would the select query return no result? Should I specify the number with three decimals in the where clause?

Update 2020-02-09:

The log output from Postgres shows the following:

```
2020-02-09 05:43:45.679 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM "ttnmapper_frequencies"  WHERE ("ttnmapper_frequencies"."mega_herz" = $1) ORDER BY "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2020-02-09 05:43:45.679 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '868.2999877929688'
2020-02-09 05:43:45.688 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper LOG:  statement: BEGIN READ WRITE
2020-02-09 05:43:45.689 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT  INTO "ttnmapper_frequencies" ("mega_herz") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id"
2020-02-09 05:43:45.689 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '868.2999877929688'
2020-02-09 05:43:45.704 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ttnmapper_frequencies_mega_herz_key"
2020-02-09 05:43:45.704 UTC [59458] ttnmapper@ttnmapper DETAIL:  Key (mega_herz)=(868.300) already exists.
```

The query

`SELECT * FROM "ttnmapper_frequencies"  WHERE ("ttnmapper_frequencies"."mega_herz" = 868.2999877929688) ORDER BY "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`

returns no results.

But however the query

`SELECT * FROM "ttnmapper_frequencies"  WHERE ("ttnmapper_frequencies"."mega_herz" = 868.3) ORDER BY "ttnmapper_frequencies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`

returns a single row.

I therefore have to assume Postgres does not automatically round parameters for select queries. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Is it possible that GORM doesn't recognize quoted names or that they need some escape character?

Comment: I'd set `log_statement = all` in PostgresSQL and see the statement that is actually executed.

Comment: Yes, adding log output shows what is going on. Original post updated.

Comment: Well if the column contains the value `868.3` then obviously comparing it to `868.2999877929688` won't return anything. If you want to compare rounded values, you need to use `round()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I changed the MegaHerz field's data type in the golang struct definition from a float64 to a decimal.Decimal.

```
type Frequency struct {
    ID          uint
    MegaHerz    decimal.Decimal `gorm:"unique;not null;type:numeric(7,3)"`
    Packets     []Packet
}
```

You do however need to include a third party library for the decimal.Decimal fixed point type.

`import "github.com/shopspring/decimal"`